# Adobe Brackets SFTP/FTP

Tags: ftp, sftp, adobe-brackets

I've been scouring the web since I got home from work, and to no avail I've yet to find a working Adobe Brackets SFTP(Preferably) or FTP extension.

If anyone know's of one that I've possibly missed, please hook me up!

Comment: Synapse is good, but be sure to expand the tab or you wont see all the add server icons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the new best one! eqftp.  This is better because it allows you to browse the server. Version 0.7 adds support for sftp as well.

https://github.com/Equals182/eqFTP

Since this was marked as the right answer I will also say that even though this is the best brackets plugin, I have found that atom's Remote FTP is the best and most reliable sftp editor I have found: https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp

Comment: eqFTP is unfortunately discontinued. Atoms Remote FTP is something I can recommend though.

Comment: eqFTP is no longer recommended. Many bugs and problems although it does still work just about.

Answer (score 12):

The [FTP-Sync extension](https://github.com/timburgess/brackets-ftp-sync) is newer and more actively maintained than the one mentioned in other answers. Give it a try!

Comment: Doesn't support sftp - a big minus for any serious development environment using a remote server.

Comment: Looks like someone has already filed that request: https://github.com/timburgess/brackets-ftp-sync/issues/4

Comment: And as of 11 days ago, that seems also implemented. As a paid version of the plugin.

Comment: It's not supporting sftp. The one support sftp is not free. $24.95. I think it's quite expensive as a extension.

Answer (score 7):

A decent workaround is to use Brackets as default editor in [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io/).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest it could be worth trying https://github.com/bigeyex/brackets-sftp-upload . They seems to be actively working.

Comment: I like this over FTP-Sync because it can upload individual files instead of checking your entire folder for changes which can take a long time

Comment: This is also my favourite, but there is a PR for multiple server settings, a bit buggy and not implemented. Seems to me it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at https://github.com/theproducer/brackets-ftp? The support seems a little bit basic for now, but this seems to be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing available yet that I know of - I'm looking for the same thing. The  https://github.com/theproducer/brackets-ftp is promising but still a long ways from being a solution.  Hopefully soon!

Comment: Hope it'll be free. Because one of the most important reason I select bracket is because it's free. I don't want to pay for its extensions.